# OTP_DSL not getting compiled with Elixir 14.3/Mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Do anybody else is also facing the same issue, when doing "mix deps.compile" with otp_dsl library using elixir 14.3 version. Please share resolution if possible.

```
Compilation error on file lib/otp_dsl/genfsm.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/otp_dsl/genfsm.ex:46: unsupported option :hygiene given to quote
(elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:487: :elixir_exp."-validate_opts/5-lc$^0/1-0-"/5
(elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:482: :elixir_exp.expand_opts/5
(elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:173: :elixir_exp.expand/2
(stdlib) lists.erl:1352: :lists.mapfoldl/3
(stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
(elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:49: :elixir_exp.expand/2
(elixir) src/elixir_exp_clauses.erl:16: :elixir_exp_clauses.def/5
(elixir) src/elixir.erl:170: :elixir.erl_eval/3
```

GIT: https://github.com/pragdave/otp_dsl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases) `:hygiene` in `quote` is deprecated since 0.13.3.

You should open an issue on the `otp_dsl` repository (which has not been updated since March...), or fork it and patch it yourself.